# A column naming conflict between joining tables, including an EAV and a straight table

Tags: sql, django, entity-attribute-value

We have an internal fork of [EAV-Django](https://readthedocs.org/projects/eav-django/) and have upgraded it to Python 3, so our internal fork is similar to the new repository of [`django-eav2`](https://django-eav2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In the application, we need to join the `transaction` table with 1) the `eav` table's email records and 2) the `customer` table. We use Django `annotate()` function to automatically generate the sample SQL code below, and please refer to the join clauses as:

```sql
  ...
left outer join `eav_value` eav_email on
  ...
left outer join `app_customer` on
  ...
```

The problem is a naming conflict: we get a column named `email` from the `eav_value` table, and the `customer` table also contains a column named `email`. Therefore, when intending to sort by the EAV's `email` attribute, the clause `order by email asc` triggers an error saying "Column 'email' in order clause is ambiguous".

**Question:**

We could rename the EAV's `email` to `eav_email` but the change will trigger other changes on the frontend, because the frontend component relies on the column name `email` or `customer.email`.

So, we wonder if there is any way to give a parent annotation to EAV attribute, e.g. in SQL query, we do instead of `eav_email.value_text as email`, we can do `eav_email.value_text as eav.email,`. If yes, how to translate this idea into Django context?

If the above thoughts are not working, we will also highly appreciate any hints and suggestions in other directions.

```sql
select
  `app_transaction`.`id`,
  eav_email.`value_text` as `email`,
  `app_customer`.`email`
from
  `app_transaction`
left outer join `eav_value` eav_email on
  (`app_transaction`.`id` = eav_email.`entity_id`
    and (eav_email.`entity_ct_id` = 28)
      and (eav_email.`attribute_id` = 56))
left outer join `app_customer` on
  (`app_transaction`.`id` = `app_customer`.`transaction_id`)
where
  `app_transaction`.`product_id` = 709
-- order by
--   `email` asc
-- 
-- If not commented out, the `order by` clause triggers the below error:
-- SQL Error [1052] [23000]: (conn=14) Column 'email' in order clause is ambiguous
;
```